# Copying a file with Drive API v3 doesn't change title or location

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use v3 of the Drive API to copy a file. Although I'm successful in getting a copy of the file to be created, neither the copied file's title nor location is changed as I had hoped. Looking at code snippets available online, I'm not sure what's wrong with my code, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def copy(service, file_id, dest_id): #Drive service, id of file to be copied, id of destination folder
    service.files().copy(
        fileId=file_id,
        supportsAllDrives=True,
        body = {
                'title':'copiedFile',
                'parents' : [ {'kind':"drive#fileLink",
                                'id': dest_id}],
                }
        ).execute()
```

Answer (score 2):

Managed to figure this out own by own, it turned out to be a fairly simple approach - here's the code for a function that handles copying a single file.

```
#Handles copying of a file.
#If no new destination (parent) is provided, it is copied
#into the same location the original file was located.

def copy(service, fileID, parents=None):
    mimetype = service.files().get(fileId=fileID, fields='mimeType', supportsAllDrives=True).execute()['mimeType']
    if mimetype == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder': #If the provided file id points to a folder
        #Code to handle copying a folder
    else:
        file_metadata = {}
        if parents is not None: #If custom destination is specified, add it to the file metadata
            file_metadata['parents'] = [parents]

        #Copy the file
        file = service.files().copy(
            fileId=fileID,
            body=file_metadata,
            fields='id, name', #Can be whatever fields you want, I just like having access to the resulting file id & name
            supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the file first, then update it by first removing the current parents and then adding the ID of the new parent folder. Here's a snippet that should do the trick:

```
copy = (
    service.files()
    .copy(
        fileId=file_id,
        body={"title": "copiedFile"},
    )
    .execute()
)

service.files().update(
    fileId=copy.get("id"),
    addParents=dest_id,
    removeParents=copy.get("parents"),
    fields="id, parents",
).execute()
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! The only issue I have with this is that, although this works on regular Google Drive files, if it's a file on a shared drive, it returns the error `A shared drive item must have exactly one parent.` This occurs even if `supportsAllDrives=True`

Comment: Away from my computer now, but I assume you'd be able to find additional documentation from Google regarding that protocol, does stripping the existing parents not work?

Comment: I assume you're referring to `removeParents`? Unfortunately, no this doesn't work. I tried running `print(copy.get('parents'))` prior to `update()`, but all it returns is `None`. Also, looking up this error, the only useful documentation is [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-shareddrives#permission_propagation), which essentially just says that a file within a shared drive can't have two locations. So perhaps the original location id isn't being removed properly? Not sure. It works if the file is My Drive -> My Drive or My Drive -> Shared, but not Shared->Shared.

Comment: @OxxoCode have you found an answer to this problem yet?

Comment: @fhcat yeah I figured it out eventually - just posted an answer with the code I ended up using. It's worked fine for me so far. Let me know if it gives you any issues or if you have any questions!